# Explanations for a complete noob

Tags: programming

Ok, so I'm thinking of switching to Ubuntu for all but gaming and CAD (I'm an engineering student). I've never tried any form of Linux (unless Android counts), so I don't know the first thing about it. My main question is:

How user-/idiot-friendly is it? Do I need to be adept at programming to use Ubuntu? I've heard the joke that Linux is the Ikea of OS's, but I've only done very basic Matlab and Python. So any advanced (or even basic) command line use will probably be beyond me. Any advice/tips?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: +1 @Oli - one of the great things aout Ubuntu is that you can try it from a "live environment" from the CD without making any changes to the computer.

Comment: Everyone of us users started basically as noobs. Maybe just start with a small(er) ubuntu-partition, you additionally set up to your main one and give it a go. It is always helpful to know a few bits about command-line use of course, but you also have GUI based applications, that get the job done in the beginning. Also linux/ubuntu is well coverd and documented when it comes to information.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use the command line or program in Linux any more or less then any other OS. If you wish to do so, you may find it easier.

Many Ubuntu users never program or use the command line.

For the most part, Python is the same on any OS.

One thing you should understand, however, is Linux is not a drop in replacement for Windows and in general your windows applications / programs will not easily run on Linux.

I suggest you boot Ubuntu and see if you like it. You can also test it in Virtualbox.